# rnoaa air pressure looping

Tags: r, function, loops, rnoaa

The rnoaa package only allows you to gather 30 days worth of air pressure information at a time https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rnoaa/rnoaa.pdf. I'm looking to create a function/ for loop to pull data from the package a month at a time. It's specific the date format that is requires, YYYYMMDD. No - or /. I started with a function, but the lapply, doesn't seem to be applying to the function to call the air pressure data.

I have tried loops in many ways, and I can't seem to get it. Here's an example.

```
for (i in dates)) {
  air_pressure[i] <- coops_search(begin_date = start[i], end_date = end[i], 
   station_name = 8727520, product= "air_pressure", units = "metric", time_zone = "gmt")
  print(air_pressure[i])
}

start<-seq(as.Date("2015/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 100)
start <- as.numeric(gsub("-","",start))

end<-seq(as.Date("2015/02/01"), by = "month", length.out = 100)
end <- as.numeric(gsub("-","",end))

pressure_function<- function(air_pressure) { 
     coops_search(station_name = 8727520, begin_date = starting,
               end_date = ending, product = "air_pressure")
}

lapply(pressure_function, starting= start, ending= end, FUN= sum)
```

No real error messages, just don't populate, or run the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some pretty fundamental things wrong here. First, your for loop has too many closing parentheses. Second, your `lapply` call passes a function as the first parameter; that does not work, pass it in the second slot. And more ....

Anyway, try this:

```r
library(rnoaa)
fun <- function(begin, end) {
  coops_search(station_name = 8727520, begin_date = gsub("-", "", begin),
    end_date = gsub("-", "", end), product = "air_pressure")
}
start_dates <- seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by = "month")
end_dates <- seq(as.Date("2015-02-01"), as.Date("2016-01-01"), by = "month") - 1
res <- Map(fun, start_dates, end_dates)
df <- dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(res, "[[", "data"))
head(df)
#>                     t      v     f
#> 1 2015-01-01 00:00:00 1025.3 0,0,0
#> 2 2015-01-01 00:06:00 1025.4 0,0,0
#> 3 2015-01-01 00:12:00 1025.5 0,0,0
#> 4 2015-01-01 00:18:00 1025.6 0,0,0
#> 5 2015-01-01 00:24:00 1025.6 0,0,0
#> 6 2015-01-01 00:30:00 1025.6 0,0,0
NROW(df)
#> [1] 87600
```

Comment: *Anyway, try this:* ... Please explain in words what to try as you recommend another apply family function. Also, you can stay in base R with `do.call(rbind, ...)` replacing `dplyr::bind_rows(...)`.